# Turbo Frame always targeting _top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, turbolinks

I have a turbo frame within a rails app:

```html
<%= turbo_frame_tag :foo, :src =>  foo_path %>
```

and inside this frame is a some simple html:

```html
<%= turbo_frame_tag :foo do %>
    <a href="/foo" data-turbo-frame="_self">Foo</a>
<% end -%>
```

However, regardless of what I put in `data-turbo-frame` (`_self` or `foo`) the link always targets top.  This is the only turbo frame in this part of the DOM, and the others have unique names.

What would cause this to happen?  The [documentation](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#targeting-navigation-into-or-out-of-a-frame) states:

> By default, navigation within a frame will target just that frame.

Comment: not skilled with turbo frames, but as far as I know every frame must have a unique id. Have you tried renaming one of them? Both of them are called :foo

Comment: Try omitting the `:src =>  foo_path` tag and instead only use the link tag (<a>).